# WPF Menuitem behaves differently from windows 7 to 10

Tags: wpf, windows-7, menuitem, windows-10

Just migrating from windows 7 to windows 10, same code, same visual studio version (2015). On a menu item that previously displayed a full size image (40x40 pixels - image is really 40x40), now on windows 10, the image is smaller (never fills the 40x40 space), and the header text information is shown. Even removing the header information text, the image never grows to fully occupy the available space.

I also tested with  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", and still no luck.
The only way that I can fill up the space is to add negative margins on the image, that seems to me not correct. Something like:

```
<Image Source="../Resources/Images_40x40/Image_Update_40x40.png" Margin="0,-8,-14,-6"/>
```

Since I do not have enough reputation, I cannot upload images, so it is hosted in:

http://postimg.org/image/nmew6u8gp/ea6f0236/

Any ideia?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was obtained using the property Header of the menu item.

```
            <MenuItem>
                <MenuItem.Header>
                    <Image Source="../Resources/Images_40x40/Image_Update_40x40.png"/>
                </MenuItem.Header>
            </MenuItem>
```

However, note that the behaviour from Windows 7 to 10 exists as described in the initial post.